# Building JSON url String

Tags: java, json, string, http, url

This is going to be a pretty ridiculous question so brace yourselves.
I need to build an URL string which will update some status variables in a website.
Basically, since the structure of the URL must be in JSON's structure, I'm having a lot of trouble getting variables in the middle of the string.

```
"http://mywebsite.com/index.php?data={\"Number\":\"1234567890001\",\"TS\":\"15/11/15%2008:08:31:44\",\"SER\":\"53543D303B44723D4E616F\"}"
```

Basically, I need to replace "1234567890001\" for the variable numberX and "53543D303B44723D4E616F\" for the variable serX.

Can someone lend me a hand?
I've tried everything with +'s & company but I'm not being able to pull it up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, It's hard to understand why you are not using GET parameter. It will be a lot more easy to get all parameters

However, if you want to stay with this approach, you can simply get your *data* value and make a replace, like : `replace("\\","")`

This will provide a String similar to this : `{"Number":"1234567890001","TS":"15/11/15%2008:08:31:44","SER":"53543D303B44723D4E616F"}`

And then, you can simply parse it using JSON Library like GSON.